# The Command to enter login items is not working in 10.8

Tags: macos, mac, terminal

I am entering the login item from the terminal but, this command is not working for me:

```
defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/loginwindow AutoLaunchedApplicationDictionary -array-add '{Path="/Applications/Your Application.app";}'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I didn't have AutoLaunchedApplicationDictionary in `~/Library/Preferences/loginwindow.plist` but only in `/Library/Preferences/loginwindow.plist`.

Most login items are stored in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginitems.plist`. The paths are stored as alias data, but you can also add login items with AppleScript:

`osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to make new login item at end with properties {path:"/Applications/TextEdit.app", name:"TextEdit", hidden:true}'`