# Why is bash echoing instead of running Apple Script

Tags: terminal, applescript, bash

I have a function in my `.bash_profile` that should allow me to add startup items. The only issue is this echo's a string instead of running the Apple Script.

This is my function

```
function addtologin(){
    if [ $3 = "hidden" ]; then
        osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to make new login item at end with properties {path:"${1}/${2}.app", name:"${2}", hidden:true}'
    else
        osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to make new login item at end with properties {path:"$1/$2.app", name:"$2", hidden:false}'
    fi
}
```

When I run `addtologin /Users/iProgram/Applications Spotify hidden` it outputs `login item ${2}`.

Why is this? Why doesn't it adding Spotify to the Login items?

If it helps, here is my full `.bash_profile` incase it is causing an issue (don't think it is)

**.bash_profile**

```
source .colors
export PS1=${BOLD}${CYAN}\\W\ \\A$\ ${DEFAULTCOLOR}
export SUDO_PS1=\\W\ \\A#\
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/iProgram/bin
export EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim

function ipaddress(){
    ifconfig en0 | awk '/inet / {print $2}'
}

function macaddress(){
    ifconfig en0 | awk '/ether/ {print toupper($2)}'
}

function wifi-off(){
    networksetup -setairportpower en0 off
}

function wifi-on(){
    networksetup -setairportpower en0 on
}

function wifi-connect(){
    networksetup -setairportnetwork en0 $1 $2
}

function nano(){
    vim $@
}

function home(){
    cd ~
}

function addtologin(){
    if [ $3 = "hidden" ]; then
        osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to make new login item at end with properties {path:"${1}/${2}.app", name:"${2}", hidden:true}'
    else
        osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to make new login item at end with properties {path:"${1}/${2}.app", name:"${2}", hidden:false}'
    fi
}
```

**.colors**

```
export BLACK='\033[0;30m'
export RED='\033[0;31m'
export GREEN='\033[0;32m'
export BROWN='\033[0;33m'
export BLUE='\033[0;34m'
export PURPLE='\033[0;35m'
export CYAN='\033[0;36m'
export LIGHTGREY='\033[0;37m'

export DARKGREY='\033[1;30m'
export LIGHTRED='\033[1;31m'
export LIGHTGREEN='\033[1;32m'
export YELLOW='\033[1;33m'
export LIGHTBLUE='\033[1;34m'
export LIGHTPURPLE='\033[1;35m'
export LIGHTCYAN='\033[1;36m'
export WHITE='\033[1;37m'

export DEFAULTCOLOR='\033[0m'
export BOLD='\033[1m'
```

If it helps, I got the osascript from [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/83016/112840)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem are the single quotes in `osascript -e '...'`. Single quotes prevent variable expansion. This means that `${2}` remains `${2}` instead of being replaced with `Spotify` for example.

Try this:

```
function addtologin(){
    if [ $3 = "hidden" ]; then
        osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to make new login item with properties {path:\"${1}/${2}.app\", name:\"${2}\", hidden:true}"
    else
        osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to make new login item with properties {path:\"${1}/${2}.app\", name:\"${2}\", hidden:false}" 
    fi
}
```

Here we use double quotes which allow for expansion. To not confuse them with the inner quotes we need to escape those with `\`.

Now running the command with `Spotify` will output `login item Spotify`. This is just the result from the AppleScript, a login item was created. To suppress this you can add `>/dev/null` to the command: `osascript -e "tell ..." >/dev/null`.